# How to push values from 1 dimensional array to 2 dimensional array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, binary, translation

This is my first question on this forum. I am a novice programmer. Currently, I working on an app which returns an English translated sentence of the passed binary string. Here is my code:

```
function binaryAgent(str) {      

  var binArr = str.split('');
  var res = [];
  var binary = [128, 64, 32, 16, 8 , 4, 2, 1];
  var k = -1;
  var matrix = [];
  var noSpace = str.replace(/\s+/g, '');

  for(var m=0; m<noSpace.length; m++){
      if(m % 8 === 0){
        k++;
        matrix[k] = []; 
      }
        matrix[k].push(noSpace[m]); 
  }

  for(var i=0; i<matrix.length; i++){
    for(var j=0; j<matrix[i].length; j++){
      if(matrix[i][j] == 1){
        res.push(binary[j]);
      }
    }
  }

  return res;
}

binaryAgent("01000001 01110010 01100101 01101110 00100111 01110100 00100000 
            01100010 01101111 01101110 01100110 01101001 01110010 01100101 
            01110011 00100000 01100110 01110101 01101110 00100001 00111111");
```

In the second for loop, I iterate through 'matrix' array to find values of 1. When I find it I am pushing appropriate value from 'binary' array. And I stuck in one place.

Function returns an array 'res' with values altogether:

```
[64, 1, 64, 32, 16, 2, 64, 32, 4, 1, 64, 32, 8, 4, 2, 32, 4, 2, 1, 64, 32, 16, 4, 32, 64, 32, 2, 64, 32, 8, 4, 2, 1, 64, 32, 8, 4, 2, 64, 32, 4, 2, 64, 32, 8, 1, 64, 32, 16, 2, 64, 32, 4, 1, 64, 32, 16, 2, 1, 32, 64, 32, 4, 2, 64, 32, 16, 4, 1, 64, 32, 8, 4, 2, 32, 1, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]
```

Problem is that I do not to know how to sum appropriate values in 'res' array. 
I would get a return something like that:

```
[[64, 1], [64, 32, 16, 2], [64, 32, 4, 1], [64, 32, 8, 4, 2] etc ..]
```

Then I will be able to sum values in particular arrays and after that using fromCharCode() I will return a sentence in English.

Anyone know how to get an array like above? Or to sum appropriate values in another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you should be able to use a similar technique in your second loop. Just push a fresh array into `res` before starting your inner loop and then push values into that array in the inner loop:

```js
function binaryAgent(str) {

      var binArr = str.split('');
      var res = [];
      var binary = [128, 64, 32, 16, 8 , 4, 2, 1];
      var k = -1;
      var matrix = [];
      var noSpace = str.replace(/\s+/g, '');

      for(var m=0; m<noSpace.length; m++){
          if(m % 8 === 0){
            k++;
            matrix[k] = [];
          }
          matrix[k].push(noSpace[m]);
      }

      for(var i=0; i<matrix.length; i++){
        res[i] = []
        for(var j=0; j<matrix[i].length; j++){
          if(matrix[i][j] == 1){
            res[i].push(binary[j]);
          }
        }
      }
      return res;
    }

var ar = binaryAgent("01000001 01110010 01100101 01101110 00100111 01110100 00100000 01100010 01101111 01101110 01100110 01101001 01110010 01100101 01110011 00100000 01100110 01110101 01101110 00100001 00111111");
console.log(ar)
```

You didn't ask, but as an aside, you can also get rid of some of the loops if you want to make the code a little tidier:

```js
function binaryAgent(str) {
      var binary = [128, 64, 32, 16, 8 , 4, 2, 1];
      var k = -1;
      var matrix = str.split(/\s+/).map(i => Array.from(i))

      return matrix.map(a => a.reduce((a, c, i) => {
        if(c == 1) {
            a.push(binary[i])
        }
        return a
      }, []))
    }

var ar = binaryAgent("01000001 01110010 01100101 01101110 00100111 01110100 00100000 01100010 01101111 01101110 01100110 01101001 01110010 01100101 01110011 00100000 01100110 01110101 01101110 00100001 00111111");
console.log(ar)
```

Comment: Glad it worked @wlodekD -- see edit for a different approach.

Comment: with map() method use it looks way more DRY than mine code

Answer (score 0):

And here is a ready app:

```
function binaryAgent(str) {

  var binArr = str.split('');
  var res = [];
  var binary = [128, 64, 32, 16, 8 , 4, 2, 1];
  var k = -1;
  var matrix = [];
  var noSpace = str.replace(/\s+/g, '');
  var sum = [], res2 = [], result = [];

  for(var m=0; m<noSpace.length; m++){
      if(m % 8 === 0){
        k++;
        matrix[k] = []; 
      }
        matrix[k].push(noSpace[m]); 
  }

  for(var i=0; i<matrix.length; i++){
    res[i] = [];
    for(var j=0; j<matrix[i].length; j++){
      if(matrix[i][j] == 1){
        res[i].push(binary[j]);
      }
    }
  }

  function getSum(total, num){
    return total + num;
  }

  for(var x=0; x<res.length; x++){
    for(var y=0; y<res[x].length; y++){
     sum[x] = res[x].reduce(getSum);
    }  
  }

  for(var z=0; z<sum.length; z++){
    res2[z] = String.fromCharCode(sum[z]);
  }

  result = res2.join('');

  return result;
}

binaryAgent("01000001 01110010 01100101 01101110 00100111 01110100 00100000 01100010 01101111 01101110 01100110 01101001 01110010 01100101 01110011 00100000 01100110 01110101 01101110 00100001 00111111");
```

I am aware that the code is not the highest quality, but today I have learned a lot. Once again thanks to Mark_M!